# Sublime Text 2 'text bubbling'?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, sublime-text-2

In vim and Notepad++ I have an awesome feature either mapped or built in that I've seen called text bubbling. I know about the Sublime documentation for mapping my own, but wanted to make sure I wasn't duplicating functionality:

Basically when I have either block of text selected, or just a cursor on a line, I push (ctrl + up/down) or some other mapping, and the text is moved up or down, in a block, and the rest of the text 'flows' around it.

Is this a native feature in Sublime Text or should I script it in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the command that controls this:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+up"], "command": "swap_line_up" },
    { "keys": ["super+down"], "command": "swap_line_down" }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sublime Text 2 doesn't appear to have that functionality. You can move whole lines, with `ctrl + cmd + up/down`, but not a smaller selection within a line.

I notice that you're using OSX. For what it's worth, [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) has the functionality you're after. I haven't used Textwrangler in a while, so I can't say for sure whether it has this feature. It is a very good free text editor, and worth investigating regardless.

Edit: I tried Textwrangler, and while it's still a good editor, it doesn't have the feature that you're after.

However, if you're a Vim user, I've heard good things about [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

Comment: Sublime Text 2 is not free, you are required to purchase a licence for continued use... It's just not enforced.

Comment: Absolutely true Ben, removed that pointless and incorrect phrease.